# Please hide my ignored tags in the "Unanswered Tags" on the unanswered tab

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered-questions, ignored-tags

If I'm not interested in **[bar]** then I *really* have no interest in looking at how many unanswered **[bar]** questions there are.

On that, I'd like the option of not having to see my ignored tags show up in the right column of the [Unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).

Some people might be interested in seeing this, so maybe it could be a per-user option.

Comment: Do you have checked `Hide ignore tags`?

Comment: Tags, tabs, tags... Make up your mind already!

Answer (score 2):

I've run into several questions that are tagged with both tags I'm interested in as well as those I'm not.  And some I've been able to answer because the issue wasn't necessarily related to the "ignored tag".  So if it would be implemented, it should be a per-user option to hide/show ignored tags.

If it did exist, I'd want it to apply site-wide rather than just the Unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

> I've run into several questions that
>   are tagged with both tags I'm
>   interested in as well as those I'm
>   not.

This is irrelevant to the issue at hand.  It wouldn't affect which questions are listed, just which tags are easily accessible in the tag list in the right column.